# A+B=AB for matrices and infinite dimensional setting

Tags: matrices

Let A and B be linear operators on a Hilbert space, say.

I can show that A+B=AB implies that AB=BA for finite square matrices.

Does this remain true for an infinite dimensional setting?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

No. Consider $\ell^2$. Define $S, T \in L(\ell^2)$ by 
\begin{align*}
  Sx &= (0,x_0, x_1, \ldots), \quad x = (x_0, x_1, \ldots)\in \ell^2\\
  Tx &= (x_1, x_2, \ldots).
\end{align*}
Note that $TS = \def\I{\mathrm{Id}_{\ell^2}}\I$, but $ST \ne \I$. Now let $A := \I-T$, $B := \I- S$. Then 
\begin{align*}
    AB &= TS - S - T + \I\\
       &= \I - \I + A - \I + B + \I\\
       &= A + B\\
    BA &= ST - T - S + \I\\
       &= ST - \I + A -\I + B + \I\\
       &= (ST - \I) + A + B\\
       &\ne A + B = AB.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks a lot for your elegant and prompt answer...